# Showing DataGridView values with a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, forms, datagridview

I want to show each value of a `DataGridView` in a message box, but it's not working.

I got an error message saying

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
private void btn_Clientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Banco banco = new Banco();

    string sql = "select * from clientes where nome <> '' or nome <> null", cn;

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable = banco.executarConsultaGenerica(sql);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;


    for (int rindex = 0; rindex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rindex++)
    {
        for (int cindex = 0; cindex < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; cindex++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[rindex,cindex].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: You don't test for NULL that way in SQL, you use `IS NOT NULL`. But your problem is in your data which we do not have access to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should check and see if …. `dataGridView1[rindex,cindex].Value` … is `null` BEFORE you try and call its `ToString()` method.